# Code produces inaccurate graph for fresnel diffraction

Tags: python, graph, integration

I've been trying to plot a graph of the 1d, horizontal diffraction pattern and have written the following code:

```
import math
import cmath
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

lamda=0.2
k=(2*math.pi)/lamda
z=0.005

def expfunc(x,xp):


    return cmath.exp(1j*k*((x-xp)**2)/(2*z))



def X(xp1,xp2,x,xp,expfunc,N):

     h=(xp2-xp1)/N
    y=0.0

    for i in np.arange(1, N/2 +1): #summing odd order y terms

        y+=4*expfunc(x,xp)
        xp+=2*h

    xp=xp1+2*h
    for i in np.arange(0, N/2): #summing even order y terms

        y+=2*expfunc(x,xp)
        xp+=2*h

    integral= (h/3)*(y+expfunc(x, xp1)+expfunc(x, xp2))    

    integral= (integral.real)**2

    return integral


NumPoints = 90000
xmin = 0
xmax =20
dx = (xmax - xmin) / (NumPoints - 1)
xvals = [0.0] * NumPoints
yvals = np.zeros(NumPoints) 
for i in range(NumPoints):
    xvals[i] = xmin + i * dx
    yvals[i] = X(xmin,xmax,xvals[i],0.1,expfunc,200)
plt.plot(xvals,yvals)
plt.show()
```

The graph is meant to be a sinc function, however the graph I get is all over the place when I vary the parameters N, the number of intervals, and z, the distance from the screen. I fail to see what is wrong with my code

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the frequency. Are you maybe missing a minus sign in `expfunc()` at `return cmath.exp(1j*k*...` ?

Comment: no, i don't think it's that- I was given the equation which needed to be integrated, and there shouldn't be a minus sign

Comment: Could you please check the upper and lower limits?

Comment: i dont think it's the limits- i had a check and it changes the shapeof the graph but is still as disordered as before

Comment: Could you test with one of scipy's integrate functions https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html?